# We have nested list create dictionary key as word list and the number of times they occur as values

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Actual Code  is :**

```
big_list = [[['one', 'two'], ['seven', 'eight']], [['nine', 'four'], ['three', 'one']], [['two', 'eight'], ['seven', 'four']], [['five', 'one'], ['four', 'two']], [['six', 'eight'], ['two', 'seven']], [['three', 'five'], ['one', 'six']], [['nine', 'eight'], ['five', 'four']], [['six', 'three'], ['four', 'seven']]]

word_counts = {}  
for n in big_list:
    for i in big_list:
        if n == i:
            word_counts[i] = word_counts[i] + 1


print(word_counts)
```

**Error is :**

> unhashable type: 'list' on line 8

**Expected result:**

> ['one':3 , 'two': 5, 'three': 4 ,.....] like that
>
> So please help me find correct solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) in order to flatten the nested list and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count how many times each element occurs:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain(*chain(*big_list)))
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'four': 5, 'one': 4, 'two': 4, 'seven': 4, 'eight': 4, 'three': 3, 
         'five': 3, 'six': 3, 'nine': 2})
```

---

For a solution without imports you can do something like:

```
d = {}
for i in big_list:
    for j in i:
        for k in j:
            if not d.get(k):
                d[k] = 1
            else:
                d[k] += 1

print(d)
# {'one': 4, 'two': 4, 'seven': 4, 'eight': 4, 'nine': 2, 
#  'four': 5, 'three': 3, 'five': 3, 'six': 3}
```

Comment: can we do without using module/libaray??

Comment: Let me post another alternative

Comment: And if nested dictionary instead of the list so which time how to count value same keys but different sub-dicionary

Comment: I'm  not sure what you mean @MahendraSeervi... unfortunately this seems like a different question, so I'd recommend you ask a new question, and you'll surely get it answered soon enough :-)

Comment: Hii @yatu how to iterate nested dictionary using loop and print key and values

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
big_list = [[['one', 'two'], ['seven', 'eight']], [['nine', 'four'], ['three', 'one']], [['two', 'eight'], ['seven', 'four']], [['five', 'one'], ['four', 'two']], [['six', 'eight'], ['two', 'seven']], [['three', 'five'], ['one', 'six']], [['nine', 'eight'], ['five', 'four']], [['six', 'three'], ['four', 'seven']]]

word_counts= {}

for ch in big_list:

    for word in ch:

              for req in word:

                     if req not in word_counts:

                                word_counts[req] = 0

                     word_counts[req]+=1

print(word_counts)
```

Comment: Please have a read of the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve the formatting in your answer, and also check out [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```py
big_list = [
    [["one", "two"], ["seven", "eight"]],
    [["nine", "four"], ["three", "one"]],
    [["two", "eight"], ["seven", "four"]],
    [["five", "one"], ["four", "two"]],
    [["six", "eight"], ["two", "seven"]],
    [["three", "five"], ["one", "six"]],
    [["nine", "eight"], ["five", "four"]],
    [["six", "three"], ["four", "seven"]],
]

word_counts = {}
for lists in big_list:
    for alist in lists:
        for word in alist:
            word_counts[word] = word_counts.get(word, 0) + 1
```